# Getting Key error while performing groupby in python. Please explain whats is wrong

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, keyerror

[image]    train[['Title', 'Sirvived']].groupby(['Title'], as_index = False).mean()

Getting below error while executing the above code
KeyError: "['Sirvived'] not in index"

Comment: Google it. `Pandas KeyError: [''] not in index`

Comment: I tried but not able to find the exact problem. The column name is correct but don't know why I am getting the error?